# how to remove trinocular operator in Java8 Stream filter

Tags: java

I'm practicing refactoring and Java 8 with very simple examples of Powerball.

I used LottoRank enum to write a function that returns the matched LottoRank based on the number of matches and bonus balls.

- The 1st place is when you hit all 6 numbers.
- The 2nd place is when you hit 5 with bonus ball.
- The 3rd place is when you hit 5 without bonus ball.
- The 4th place is when you hit 4 numbers.
- The 5th place is when you hit 3 numbers.

The logic for obtaining this value is as follows.

- LottoRank

```
NONE(Integer.MIN_VALUE, 0),
  FIFTH(3, 5000),
  FOURTH(4, 50000),
  THIRD(5, 1500000),
  SECOND(5, 30000000),
  FIRST(6, 2000000000);

  private final int matchCount;
  private final Money winnerMoney;

  LottoRank(int matchCount, int winnerMoney) {
    this.matchCount = matchCount;
    this.winnerMoney = new Money(winnerMoney);
  }

  public boolean isCorrectMatchCount(int matchCount) {
    return this.matchCount == matchCount;
  }

  public int calculateWinningMoney(Integer value) {
    return winnerMoney.multiple(value);
  }

  public static LottoRank findRank(String winnerRank) {
    return LottoRankPredicates.filterLottoRankWithString(winnerRank);
  }

  public static LottoRank valueOf(int matchCount, boolean bonusBall) {
    return Arrays.stream(LottoRank.values())
        .filter(rank -> isThirdOrSecond(matchCount) ?
            filterIsSecond(bonusBall, rank.winnerMoney) : rank.matchCount == matchCount)
        .findAny()
        .orElse(LottoRank.NONE);
  }

  private static boolean isThirdOrSecond(int matchCount) {
    return matchCount == LottoRank.THIRD.matchCount;
  }

  private static boolean filterIsSecond(boolean bonusBall, Money winnerMoney) {
    return bonusBall ? winnerMoney.equals(LottoRank.SECOND.winnerMoney) : winnerMoney.equals(LottoRank.THIRD.winnerMoney);
  }

  public static LottoRank matches(List<Number> winningNumbers, List<Number> holdingLottoNumbers, Number bonusBall) {
    int matchCount =  Math.toIntExact(winningNumbers.stream()
        .filter(holdingLottoNumbers::contains)
        .count());
    boolean isSecond = holdingLottoNumbers.contains(bonusBall);
    return LottoRank.valueOf(matchCount, isSecond);
  }
```

If you look at the filter part of `valueOf()`, you will determine whether it is 2nd or 3rd (i.e., you got 5 correct). Based on whether the bonus ball has been hit or not, the logic is updated to 2nd place and if not, the ranking is processed according to the correct number.

I want to erase the trinomial operator in this part.

**However, else statements and switch-case statements are not allowed.**

I thought of a prefix or multiple filters, but eventually the first condition must be correct to run on the next condition, and this code will be generated.

It's a code that didn't work properly, but it's like this.

```
  public static LottoRank valueOf(int matchCount, boolean bonusBall) {
    return Arrays.stream(LottoRank.values())
        .filter(rank -> matchCount == rank.matchCount)
        .filter(rank -> isThirdOrSecond(matchCount))
        .filter(rank -> filterIsSecond(bonusBall, rank.winnerMoney))
        .findAny()
        .orElse(LottoRank.NONE);
  }
```

Is there a way to refactory this more?

### Edited

I was thinking about the above and i processed it with the `LottoRankPredicates` class as below.

I wonder what you think about refactoring like this.

- LottoRankPredicates

```
public class LottoRankPredicates {

  private static Predicate<LottoRank> isSecondOrThird(boolean bonusBall) {
    return rank -> getSecondOrThird(bonusBall, rank);
  }

  private static Predicate<LottoRank> defaultCase(int matchCount) {
    return rank -> rank.isCorrectMatchCount(matchCount);
  }

  private static Predicate<LottoRank> findRank(String winnerRank) {
    return rank -> rank.name().equals(winnerRank);
  }

  private static boolean getSecondOrThird(boolean bonusBall, LottoRank rank) {
    if(bonusBall) {
      return rank == LottoRank.SECOND;
    }
    return rank == LottoRank.THIRD;
  }

  public static LottoRank filterLottoRankWithString(String winnerRank) {
    return Arrays.stream(LottoRank.values())
        .filter(findRank(winnerRank))
        .findAny()
        .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
  }

  public static LottoRank filterLottoRankIsSecondOrThird(boolean bonusBall) {
    return Arrays.stream(LottoRank.values())
        .filter(isSecondOrThird(bonusBall))
        .findAny()
        .orElse(LottoRank.NONE);
  }

  public static LottoRank filterLottRankIsDefault(int matchCount) {
    return Arrays.stream(LottoRank.values())
        .filter(defaultCase(matchCount))
        .findAny()
        .orElse(LottoRank.NONE);
  }
}
```

- LottoRank

```
public static LottoRank findRank(String winnerRank) {
    return LottoRankPredicates.filterLottoRankWithString(winnerRank);
  }

  public static LottoRank valueOf(int matchCount, boolean bonusBall) {
    if(isThirdOrSecond(matchCount)) {
      return LottoRankPredicates.filterLottoRankIsSecondOrThird(bonusBall);
    }
    return LottoRankPredicates.filterLottRankIsDefault(matchCount);
  }

  private static boolean isThirdOrSecond(int matchCount) {
    return matchCount == LottoRank.THIRD.matchCount;
  }
```

Comment: @Marc I added that part, and there's a refactoring part, so I'll add this part as well.

Comment: "I want to erase the trinomial operator in this part." --> Simple: create a method returning boolean which holds that logic and give it a meaningful name. And please take this as a real world hint, as this will make your code much more readable and maintainable.

Comment: I'm confused - is all the code here for review, or only the last couple of blocks?  It would make the review request clearer if you used "blockquote" markdown (```> ```)for code that's illustrative but not for review, such as original code pre-refactoring.

Comment: @mtj thanks i got a hint from your comment

Comment: @TobySpeight sorry, just only the last couple of blocks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constants of an `enum` are *full featured classes*. This means, in any of that constants you can override any non private method of the `enum` class itself and change the behavior to something constant specific. Basically this is the OO best practice *exchange branching with inheritance*.

So the approach would be to make `filterIsSecond()` non static and add an override in the constants `SECOND` and `THIRD` like this:
<sub>(ATTENTION! My refactoring might not be semantically correct since you did not provide a [sscce](http://sscce.org)  nor unittests.)</sub>

```
    // ...
    THIRD(5, 1500000){
            @Override
            boolean filterIsSecond(boolean bonusBall, Money winnerMoney) {
                    return bonusBall && this.winnerMoney==winnerMoney;
            }
    },
    SECOND(5, 30000000){
            @Override
            boolean filterIsSecond(boolean bonusBall, Money winnerMoney) {
                    return this.winnerMoney==winnerMoney;
            }
    },
    FIRST(  //..


    boolean filterIsSecond(boolean bonusBall, Money winnerMoney) { 
            return this.matchCount == matchCount;
      }

    public static LottoRank valueOf(int matchCount, boolean bonusBall) {
            return Arrays.stream(LottoRank.values())
                    .filter(rank -> rank.filterIsSecond(bonusBall, rank.winnerMoney))
                    .findAny()
                    .orElse(LottoRank.NONE);
    }
```

Beside of that you should follow the Java naming conventions which promote methods (which you call functions) should start with a *verb* or in case they return `boolean` (as in your case) shoudl start with `is`, `can`, `has` or alike. This way the code that uses them reads much better.

Comment: Hello, fyi there is the typo @Overrode.

Comment: @dariosicily: fixed it, thank you.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle i appreciate your dedication.

However, because winnerMoney is private, there is an issue in the Override method that cannot access the value.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle 
but, I took a hint from your code and created an interface and handled it neatly.
Thank you for expanding the Insight.

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: Note: MCVE, SSCCE and similar are NOT recommended on Code Review. We prefer to see the actual code, not minimized examples of it.